# how to componentize each row of an html table in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular. I want to render each row of a html table as separate component using ngFor. I tried an approach but failed.

StackBlitz link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaie9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

In the above stackblitz link, i am rendering a table using a single component for the whole table and rendering another similar table by using two components. One for the main table and the other for the table data. Why is the latter not rendering correctly? or to be specific why is it getting rendered under first column?

Comment: Please provide a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com) example with your problem

Comment: ok. Let me compose one and get back.

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu - Please check this stackblitz link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yaie9e?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html  The commented code in app.component.html works fine. However, if i try the same thing by making the table row as a compoenent, i get an issue(table row only populates under 1st th)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure as to why the `<tr>` isn't rendered properly when it is a root element of a component, maybe someone else can answer that.  One way that has worked for me is using and attribute selector instead of an element selector.

#### app.component.html

```
...
<tbody>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let venue of venues">
    <tr app-row [venue]="venue"></tr>
  </ng-container>
</tbody>
...
```

#### app-row.component.ts

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-row]',
  templateUrl: './row.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './row.component.css' ]
})
export class RowComponent implements OnInit  { ... }
```

#### app-row.component.html

```
<td>{{venue.venueName}}</td>
<td>{{venue.userName}}</td>
<td>{{venue.hb}}</td>
```

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ymyu2q

Answer (score 1):

In your example the structure of the dom is like this:

```
tbody
  tr
    app-row
     tr
       td
       td
       td
```

So it's rendering properly, but the table is broken because of how css works.

A solution would be to remove the wrapping `tr` from the `app-row.component.html`, and change the selector property of `app-row.component.ts` to `selector: 'tr[app-row]'`, that way, you could use it as an attribute for your **tr** tag in the `app.component.html` like so:

```
<tr app-row *ngFor="let venue of venues" [venue]="venue"></tr>
```

Here's a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rfncma) example.